# How do I insert a dataframe to an oracle table illegal/variable oracle

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I have the following dataframe

```
df2 = {names: [PEPE, LUIS], id: [1,2], stages: [0,1], ord: [3, 2]}
```

but these are the required fields, the table to insert, you have more fields, which allow nulls.

And where the dataframe is equivalent to these fields in the table

```
df2 = {labels= :1, id= :2, stages= :3, ord= :4}
```

The table

```
CREATE TABLE customer_prf
(
  names      VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL, 
  label      VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL,
  type       VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL,
  type_flag  INT,
  type_flag2 INT,
  conc       VARCHAR2(80), 
  id         INT NOT NULL,
  n_stage    INT NOT NULL,
  ctry       INT NOT NULL,
  "order"    INT NOT NULL
);
```

How did you manage to insert the data from the data with the insert with values ​​already previously defined in the query string, which I am doing wrong, which ora-01036 sends me. Besides, does the `id` value auto increment itself?

My code

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

...
df2.to_dict(orient='records')
print(df2)

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connection)
cur = conn.cursor()
id = 0
insert_qry = cur.execute("insert into customer_prf values(
'references',
:1,
'text',
'',
'',
:2,
:3,
2,
:4)"
   cursor.prepare(insert)
```

how would you insert it

Comment: Your `insert_qry` string is not formatted correctly. You should not have a return (\n) in the string.

Comment: How do I put a value in that required field then? Because when inserting a defined value it is with a string in the script

Comment: remove all the returns in the string. It all needs to be on one line.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much, how do I set the id field? with the incrementable in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df2.values.tolist` in order to get a parameter list, and such a code as below in order to insert the values within the dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('un/pwd@host:port/dbname')

try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['Pepe','Luis'], 'stages': [0,1], 'order': [3, 2]}) 
    col_list = df2.values.tolist()

    cursor.prepare("INSERT INTO customer_prf(names,label,type,id,n_stage,ctry,\"order\") VALUES(:1,'references','text',seq_customer.nextval,:2,2,:3)")
    cursor.executemany(None,col_list)
    print("executed!")
except Exception as err:
    print('Error', err)
else:
    conn.commit()
```

*where*

- prefer using `executemany` rather than `execute` as being more
  performant
- create a sequence (`seq_customer`) and add to your values list
  (`seq_customer.nextval`) as using DB version 11g, if your database was of version 12c+, then the ID column could be identified within the create table ddl statement(eg. *during table creation*) such as

  `ID INT generated always as identity primary key`

Comment: I understand, thank you very much, how do I set the id field? with the incrementable in a variable?

Comment: oh, well, I missed that part @Jonathan . Just create a sequence (`seq_customer`) and add to your values list (`seq_customer.nextval`) as using DB version 11g.

Comment: I deliberately kept the DEFAULT 'references' within the creation statement, since you don't need to put that as the literal within the application. And please try with these five columns firstly, then you can gradually add the rest of the columns within your database so that not to have such a mess here @Jonathan . Moredeover the rest of the dataframe would be needed for your suggested edit.

Comment: Excuse me, I will take away, it happens, that the id field, is not primary, so generate that field from the dataframe because in the end it is only a consecutive one, then there are fields that are mandatory and others are necessary, but others are not, I do not know how to insert and send me illegal / variable

Comment: I've edited so as to get a complete case with all columns of the table @Jonathan . Btw, you can revert your edits **except** the **CREATE TABLE** statement in order the future readers of this question will easily understand the question and answer correlation.