# 1 value is not the same type as previous elements python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oracle11g

I have a dataframe, which I converted to an array of arrays with tolist (), with the following structure

```
 df2 = [['PEPE', 1, 1, 0, 'ARAUZ']...]
 where name = :1, id= :2, number_stage= :3, order= :4, last_name= :5  
and i have this tuple ("name", "id", "number_stage" "order", "last_name")
```

but in the insert, I want to set defined values, in addition to the ones I have in the dataframe

My code

```
 import cx_Oracle
    
    conn = cx_Oracle.connet(connection)
    try: 
       cur = conn.cursor()
       spt = "INSERT INTO user.table_name values('references',:1,'text',7,6,'F','A','Y','','','','',:2,:3,2,:4);"
       cur.executemany(spt, [df2])
       print("executed!")
    except Exception as err:
       print('Error', err)
    else:
       conn.commit()
```

But it returns this error element 1 value is not the same type as previous elements and not eneod because, if you can help me, please, grateful for your comments.

table structure

```
label=varchar(req)|name=varchar(req)|type=varchar(req)|type_flag=number(null)|type_flag2=numbe(null)r|conc=varchar(null)|prp=varchar(null)|active=varchar(null)|read=varchar(null)|required=varchar(null)|hint=varchar(null)|hint_img=varchar(null)|id=number(req)|n_stage=number(req)|ctry=number(req)|order=number(req)|lst_name=varchar(req)
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, what do you want to do, I already suggested `df2.values.tolist()` in order convert dataframe to list. That should solve your problem successfully. Btw, what's the structure of the table (`user.table_name`)?

Comment: Moreover, the format of the current dataframe was better(provided that the strings such as `PEPE`, `LUIS`, `Albert` are quoted such as `'PEPE'` ... etc.). Most probably, the current problem raises due to this mess of miscellanous data types such as `['PEPE', 1, 1, 0, 'ARAUZ']`.

Comment: Lastly, `order` is a reserved keyword that cannot be used as a column name for a table unless quoted (`"order"`).

Comment: Edited with the structure of the table, if I know, although the query is not there, when I write it I complete the order field between double quotes "order".

Comment: but, the data types of the columns are missing. Indeed, you can add these info which you added lastly to the previous question, this seems to be a duplicate, and so you can delete this one.

Comment: Please, have a look at your previous question's answer that I've just updated. There I kept some of your columns, you can complete the rest due to this model.

Comment: edited bro! 
Could you pass me the link of that question please, sure, what did I do? I have not received any notification of that "question"

Comment: I've meant [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598076/5841306)

Comment: you are right, what happens is that I had to create the column from the dataframe I already explain you in that question